# How do I create a list of functions in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a list of functions where each function is slightly different.  The following code works fine:

```
fun1 <- function(n) {
  fun2 <- function(x) {
    x^n
  }
  return(fun2)
}

powerfuns <- vector("list", 3)
powerfuns[[2]] <- fun1(2)
powerfuns[[3]] <- fun1(3)

powerfuns[[2]](4)
# [1] 16
powerfuns[[3]](4)
# [1] 64
```

The second element of the list is a function that squares its argument while the third is a function that cubes its argument. But it doesn't seem to work if I create the list using a for-loop instead:

```
powerfuns <- vector("list", 3)
for (i in 1:3) {
  powerfuns[[i]] <- fun1(i)
}

powerfuns[[2]](4)
# [1] 64
powerfuns[[3]](4)
# [1] 64
```

Now both functions cube their arguments. There seems to be something about the for-loop that causes the environments for the functions to be identical. get("n", environment(powerfuns[[2]])) returns 3 in the second example but 2 in the first example. Does anyone have a suggestion about how I can get the result I want using a loop or something similar? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with lazy evaulation. Since `fun1` doesn't use the value `n` you pass in right away, it doesn't capture the value in the way you expect. You can fix this with

```
fun1 <- function(n) {
  force(n)
  fun2 <- function(x) {
    x^n
  }
  return(fun2)
}
```

Then you can run the same code

```
powerfuns <- vector("list", 3)
for (i in 1:3) {
  powerfuns[[i]] <- fun1(i)
}
powerfuns[[2]](4)
# [1] 16
powerfuns[[3]](4)
# [1] 64
```